# Form of the Polar decomposition for $M_{\varphi}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Polar Decomposition:** Let $‎v$ be a continuous linear operator on a Hilbert space ‎$‎H$. Then there is a unique ‎partial ‎isometry ‎‎$‎‎u\in B(H)$ such thats ‎‎$‎‎v=u|v|‎$ and $‎‎\ker(u) = \ker(v)$ more over, $u^*v=‎|v|$.‎‎

‎
Assume that ‎$‎X$ is a compact set, $\mu$ measure on it and‎ $\varphi \in L^{\infty}(X,\mu)$‎.
‎
We define ‎$‎‎M_{‎\varphi‎}: L^{‎\infty‎}(X,\mu)‎\longrightarrow‎ L^{‎\infty‎}(X,\mu)$ ‎such ‎that ‎‎$‎‎M_{‎\varphi‎}(f)=‎\varphi ‎f‎‎‎$‎.

‎
I ‎know ‎that ‎‎$‎‎M_{‎\varphi‎}^*‎‎=‎‎M_{\overline{\varphi}‎}$.

so I can say 
$$| M_{\varphi}|=\left(M_{\varphi}^{*}M_{\varphi}\right)^{1/2}=M_{|\varphi|} $$

I want to find ‎$‎‎u$ ‎in ‎polar ‎decomposition.‎
‎

Q:What ‎is ‎‎$‎‎u$? What ‎is ‎the ‎form ‎of ‎it?‎

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

We have (by uniqueness) that $u = M_{{\mathrm sgn}\,\varphi}$, where
$$
{\mathrm sgn}\,\varphi(x) = \begin{cases}0, &\varphi(x) =0,\\
\frac{\varphi(x)}{|\varphi(x)|}, &\varphi(x)\neq 0.\end{cases}
$$